# Issues running apache Kafka on Mac

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I've installed Apache Zookeeper and Apache Kafka **([kafka_2.13-2.7.0](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart))** on my **macOS Big Sur 11.1**. Where the Zookeeper is running fine but not the Kafka.

**Java version:**

```sh
openjdk 14.0.2 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 14.0.2+12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 14.0.2+12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I'm following this [get started page](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart). The zookeeper runs fine but then when I try to run Kafka it gives me the following error.

```sh
MacBook-Pro:kafka saad$ bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
[2021-04-16 06:19:56,021] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2021-04-16 06:19:56,450] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
[2021-04-16 06:19:56,465] ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafka$)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error creating broker listeners from 'PLAINTEXT:localhost:9092': Unable to parse PLAINTEXT:localhost:9092 to a broker endpoint
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.listenerListToEndPoints(CoreUtils.scala:274)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.advertisedListeners(KafkaConfig.scala:1703)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.validateValues(KafkaConfig.scala:1778)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1756)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1312)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable$.fromProps(KafkaServerStartable.scala:34)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:68)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Unable to parse PLAINTEXT:localhost:9092 to a broker endpoint
    at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$.createEndPoint(EndPoint.scala:57)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.$anonfun$listenerListToEndPoints$6(CoreUtils.scala:271)
    at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedIterableOps.map(StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedIterableOps.map$(StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala:86)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq.map(ArraySeq.scala:38)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.listenerListToEndPoints(CoreUtils.scala:271)
    ... 7 more
```

*I tried to get an idea from the error but as I'm not a java guy I was unable to understand*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue with [Kafka](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4121) issue thread. As I'm not running the servers on docker also made it difficult to find a solution.

The problem was basically using a strict localhost IP address (I'm not clearly sure about this). Just by changing the strict ip `server.properties` in `kafka/config` directory.

```
# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, 
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

Comment: Generally, the advertised listener should be the external hostname/ip, if you want to use other machines, not localhost